# Nested SOQL Query

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql

I am new to salesforce development and want to achieve the below requirement.

We follow account hierarchy and I want to show all the opportunities, contacts of child account on parent account related list using VF.

I know we cannot query parent to child till 1 level deep. Please help how can I achieve this.

Parent Account
|
Child Account
|
Associated opportunities, contacts

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Unaware of how you want to use the data, the following query will retrieve the data needed.

```
List<Account> accounts = [
    select id, 
        (select Id from Cases), 
        (select Id from Contacts), 
        (select Id from Opportunities) 
    from Account
    WHERE id = '<Root Account ID>'
    or Account.ParentId = '<Root Account ID>'
];
```

I have placed an `or`operator in my SOQL to illustrate how you can use the Account hierarchy.

The following debug shows you the collections of Cases, Contacts and Opportunites queried.

```
for (Account a : accounts) {
    System.debug(a.Cases);
    System.debug(a.Contacts);
    System.debug(a.Opportunities);
}
```